# How to break promise chain on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Consider this snippet

```
fetch(`http://${api.host}:${api.port}/user`)
  .then(function(data) {
    return data.json();
  }, function(err) {
    throw new Error(`Couldn\'t fetch user data from server: ${err.message}`);
  }).then(function(eparkUser) {
    for (var key in eparkUser) {
      if (eparkUser.hasOwnProperty(key) && !user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        user[key] = eparkUser[key];
      }
    }
    done(null, user);
  }, function(err) {
    throw new Error(`Couldn't parse returned json: ${err.message}`);
  }).catch(function(e) {
    done(e);
  });
```

Isn't `throw` supposed to break the chain and trigger `.catch` ? How to achieve this behaviour? Becauce now both `throw` are  getting executed and I see message:

`Error: Couldn't parse returned json: Couldn't fetch user data from server: request to http://localhost:3010/user failed` and that not what I want.

P.S. `fetch` is npm `node-fetch` module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `throw` does not jump to `catch`. It does reject the promise, and all error handlers installed on it will be invoked. In your case, that's the error handler installed by the `then` call. Notice that `.catch(handler)` is just sugar for `.then(null, handler)`.

Your current code works like

```
try {
    try {
        try {
            var data = fetch(`http://${api.host}:${api.port}/user`)
        } catch(err) {
            throw new Error(`Couldn\'t fetch user data from server: ${err.message}`);
        }
        var eparkUser = data.json();
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(`Couldn't parse returned json: ${err.message}`);
    }
    for (var key in eparkUser) {
        if (eparkUser.hasOwnProperty(key) && !user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            user[key] = eparkUser[key];
        }
    }
    done(null, user);
} catch(e) {
    done(e);
}
```

To solve your problem, you'll need to nest your handlers, and install the JSON-parse-handler only on that particular promise:

```
fetch(`http://${api.host}:${api.port}/user`)
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.json()
            .then(function (eparkUser) {
                for (var key in eparkUser) {
                    if (eparkUser.hasOwnProperty(key) && !user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        user[key] = eparkUser[key];
                    }
                }
                return user;
            }, function(err) {
                throw new Error(`Couldn't parse returned json: ${err.message}`);
            });
    }, function(err) {
        throw new Error(`Couldn\'t fetch user data from server: ${err.message}`);
    })
    .then(done.bind(null, null), done);
```